# scp upload is failing with directory location missing

Tags: ssh, openssh-for-windows, opensshutils

I am using Renci.SshNet in my program trying to copy local file (windows machine) to remote WindowsServer which is running OpenSsh (client and server).

When I run below command

```
ScpClient remoteCopyClient = new ScpClient(remoteEntity.EntityIp,
                                                       remoteEntity.EntityUsername,
                                                       remoteEntity.EntityPassword);
remoteCopyClient.Connect();
remoteCopyClient.Upload(new FileInfo(@"D:\testfolder\test2.txt"), @"C:\WindowsTestFolder");
remoteCopyClient.Disconnect()
```

it gave me below error, even though the folder exist in remote location.

> Renci.SshNet.Common.ScpException: 'scp: ./C:\WindowsTestFolder: No
> such file or directory'

Actually prior to upload, there is a ssh.RunCommand(@"mkdir C:\WindowsTestFolder") that worked good and created a WindowsTestFolder in remote windows machine.